# Adding Garmin *.img files to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, contour, garmin

I downloaded 10 .img files from garmin.openstreetmap.nl which are supposed to contain the topo tiles for the area I would like to add in qgis. I've been unable to find any instructions on how to use the files in QGIS.

Can someone explain or point me to where instructions are available to accomplish this?

I need to apply contour lines to a map of Thailand in qgis.
It appears the img tiles I currently have are unusable to achieve this.

Where can I download whatever file type is necessary containing the contour lines for Thailand and by what steps, using what application can that file be converted to one which can be added as a layer to qgis?

Comment: why not download shapefiles from bbbike for qgis? Thailand example with contours 10m apart - http://extract.bbbike.org/?lang=en&sw_lng=99.50415&sw_lat=14.07272&ne_lng=99.53007&ne_lat=14.08924&format=osm.pbf&oi=1&layers=00B00000T

Comment: @Mapperz: the height data you see in OpenCycleMap is not part of the OSM database.

Comment: The Garmin maps from garmin.openstreetmap.nl don't contain any contour lines.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you are lost with your approach.

Although called .img file and "tile", this data is in fact a compacted vector format invented by Garmin, which is not supported by QGIS or GDAL.

You can use them im QLandkarteGT, which has some GIS-like features, and Garmins own BaseCamp software. But nowhere else (except the Garmin units, of course)

---

QGIS is able to create contour lines directly from SRTM heigth data with `Raster -> Extraction -> Contour`. Thats the same source garmin.osm.nl is using.

This height data is not in the Openstreetmap database, so you can not get it from the QGIS  OSM plugin.

Comment: We're trying to add contour lines to the map of Thailand we are using in qgis. We've searched everywhere, including openstreetmap trying to find a sownload containing just the contour lines, preferably 10m if possible. Is there a source for Thailand compatible with qgis available somewhere we have not be able to find?

Comment: For the contour lines, see my extended answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. First you need to convert the .img files to a .mp format. A good tool for this procedure is MapEdit. Separate each symbol to its own .mp file. Then you can convert the .mp file to .shp